# Angularjs $resource called from Directive not making request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular (V 1.1.5) Directive that makes a call to a custom service.  The Directive calls the service just fine, but the service doesn't make the request.  Code below:

```
Services.factory("storeLocator",["$resource",function($resource){
    var serviceResource=$resource("http://my.domain.com/locator",{
        country:"US",
        searchradius: "50|150",
        digits:"3"
    },{
        byCoords: {
            method:"GET",
            params: {
                longitude:"",
                latitude:""
            },
            cache:true
        },
        byZip: {
            method:"GET",
            params:{
                zip:""
            },
            cache:true
        }

    });

    return {

        byCoords:function(lon,lat,onSuccess) {


        serviceResource.byCoords({latitude:lat,longitude:lon},function(data){
                if( typeof(onSuccess)==="function"){
                    onSuccess(data);
                }
            });

        },

        byZipCode:function(zipcode,onSuccess) {
            serviceResource.byZip({address:zipcode},function(data){
                if( typeof(onSuccess)==="function") {
                    onSuccess(data);
                }
            });
        }
    };

}]);

        Directives.directive("myLocator",["storeLocator",function(storeLocator){

return{
    restrict:"AC",
    scope: {
        template:"@"
    },
    templateUrl: function(tElement,tAttrs) {

        /** Retrieve Template URL **/

    },

    controller: ["$scope",function($scope){
        var parseData=function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }

        var findStoresByGeolocation=function(position) {
            storeLocator.byCoords(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude,parseData);    
        }


        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findStoresByGeolocation);
        }
    }],

    link:function(scope,element,attrs){



    }

}
   }]);
```

Both the directive and service are in separate JS files and are injected into my module.

Like I said the Directive calls storeLocator.byCoords just fine and all parameters are passed.

I have tried calling the service from different points in the directive (link and compile functions).

On extra bit of weirdness is on page load, no request.  Click a link to load a new page, the request is made.  The directive is global on the site.

I have create services for controllers and I have not had this issue.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be related by your code running outside the Angular 'event loop' (because it's being call from a non-Angular event handler).

Try this:

```
var findStoresByGeolocation = function(position) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    storeLocator.byCoords(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude,parseData);    
  });
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to wrap the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call in case this were the issue?

Comment: @finishingmove I'm not sure, but it would still be calling a non-Angular callback in that case.

Comment: @finishingmove here's a demo for that situation: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0COjjxvgtF92eeOJKPun?p=preview)

Comment: @finishingmove that's why plunker is so cool, easy to test things :) I wasn't sure either.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the insight.  This one was baffling me.